# How do I delete one message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I was trying to do a ghostping command that pings people then deletes the message it (creates a notification but no ping) but when I used `.purge` it deleted a lot of messages I just wanted to delete one message and using .delete doesn't work for some reason :P I wanted to also delete the users command so people wont see who ghost pinged.

Here is the code I have tried:

```py
@client.command()
async def ghostping(message, member : discord.Member):
    await message.channel.send(f"<@!{member.id}>", delete_after=0)
    await message.channel.purge()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to define how many msgs you want to delete if its not specified, which should be 5 or so

```
async def ping(ctx,member: discord.Member,amt): 
  for i in range(int(amt)):
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}")
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amt)+1)
```

here i didnt state a default amount, but you can just add in ur own default amount using this method

```
async def clear(ctx,amount=5): 
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```